# Transistor operating point problem doesn't make sense?

Tags: transistors

> Find the operating point of the transistors T1 and T2.

I've been given this problem and when I try to apply Thevenin's theorem on resistors R2, R3 and then try to calculate \$I_{C1}\$, I get \$I_{C1} = 0\$ and have no idea why.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvdxdp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Sorry for the not so good explanation I'm new in this community and new in the electronics domain, it isn't really my strength. Any help will be appreciated.

Applying thevenin's on R2, R3, we get:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqLJBW.png)</sup>

If we take the loop with V1, R1, T1, V2, using K2:

$$Vcc - 0 = U_{EB}+I_{B1}*R1+ V1$$

$$I_{c1}/\beta_0 = (Vcc - V1)/R01.$$

With \$\beta_0 = 100\$ and \$U_{EB} = 0.6V\$ and approximating V1 to 9.6 we get I_c1 = 0. And it's really weird.

Comment: Show all of your work, please.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Ok, I'll try to edit the question

Comment: And please draw the ground connections towards the bottom (Rotate V1 180 degrees)

Comment: FYI, we use `\$` to start and end inline math and `$$` for display math.

Comment: Where is Vcc in your drawing? Why are you mixing up \$U\$ and \$V\$ as symbols for voltage? Why would you "approximate V1 to 9.6" if you know it is 9.393V? I think you may be rounding too much.

Comment: @C.Cristi Are you supposed to develop a set of equations, say via KCL and/or KVL, to solve here?

Comment: @ThePhoton Sorry, on math platform it's not like that

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Sorry for mixing up. Vcc is V2

Comment: @jonk Yes, it should be hand calculated

Comment: @C.Cristi, Yes, EE had to do things differently because the `$` symbol was already used in a bunch of posts to refer to money when MathJax was introduced.

Comment: @C.Cristi Are you familiar enough with nodal analysis to write the equations, then? Or what approach are you supposed to use? (You only say "Thevenin." But that's a pretty broad perch with lots of room on it.)

Comment: @jonk Not really, i'm really not the best person at this. What is the meaning of the Thevenin's theorem?

Comment: Am i the only one who is having a hard time figuring out how Q2 is supposed to work? If i'm not mistaken, in that configuration, Q2 would never be in a conductive state since current needs to flow from collector to base for it to be active yet for Vb to be lower than Vc, current needs to flow into the base. or am i missing the question completely?

Comment: @Francoislandry I saw the same thing; I wonder if Q2 is supposed to be NPN or if it's missing another resistor to ground in the base bias.

Comment: No need to do any calculations. T2 is biased off so no Collector current can flow in either transistor. Problem solved!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem isn't a good candidate for hand solution.

Because the resistor divider formed by R2 and R3 is going to have about \$(10\ V)\frac{0.6}{9.3+0.6}\approx 0.6\ V\$ across R2, and thus there is about 0.6 V across the b-e junction of T1.

That means that T1 is only very weakly turned on, and our basic rules for hand calculations don't handle this situation well. If we have a rule that the b-e junction must be -0.7 V (negative because it's a PNP) to turn the transistor on, then we think this transistor is in cut off mode. Or if we think the b-e junction needs -0.6 V to turn on then we see that the transistor is just barely turned on, but there's nothing to tell us how much current is flowing out of the base.

Even if we use the more accurate 9.393 V you calculated for the Thevenin equivalent voltage of the 10 V source and resistor divider, there's nothing to say that the b-e voltage of the transistor will be exactly -0.6 or -0.7 under these bias conditions. It might be -0.65 V or -0.55 V, and given the small difference between the Thevenin source output and the base voltage in the circuit, this will cause substantial errors in the calculation result.

The best way to solve this circuit would be to plug it in to a simulator (with reasonably chosen transistor models). Or to adjust the resistor values to be sure the transistor is either fully in active mode or fully cut off.

Comment: Why negative because it's pnp?

Comment: Because a PNP BJT enters active operation when \$V_{be} < -0.6\ \rm V\$ or so.

Comment: can you tell me more how did you get that resistor divider? and why it isn't \$ \frac {9.3}{9.3+0.6}(10 V)\$?

Comment: I was calculating the voltage across R2, instead of across R3, since that's what's relevant of finding the b-e voltage of T1. If I did it more accurately, instead of finding the voltage was 9.393 V above ground, I'd have found that it was 0.607 V below the 10 V supply node.

Comment: Can you explain more why  it's wrong to have a voltage of 0.6 V across R2 while the b-e junction is also 0.6 V? I don't really get it

Comment: It's not wrong. In fact, after loading the b-e voltage will always be equal the voltage across R2.  But if you have a thevenin voltage of -0.6 V (relative to the +10 V node) and your transistor model says that the b-e  junction acts as a 0.6 V source in forward active or saturated modes, then there's 0 V across your thevenin resistor and so 0 current, which means 0 base current. The simple model simply can't handle this situation.

Comment: I still don't get it, why then there is 0V across my thevenin resistor?

Comment: Because there's 9.4 V on one side of it and 9.4 V on the other side of it.

Comment: And it is \$V_{th} - (V_{cc}-V_{BE}) = 0\$?